# Do I need a Brazil transit visa on my way to Fiji?

Tags: transit-visas, nigerian-citizens, fiji

I am a Nigerian living in Nigeria.

I intend to travel to Fiji Island. I was asked to get a Brazil transit visa.

Secondly, do I need to get an invitation letter from someone residing in Fiji to be able to travel there?

Comment: What is your full flight itinerary? There are no flights from Brazil to Fiji, so there must be at least one more stop involved.

Comment: How are you getting from Nigeria to Fiji?  I've checked two booking sites and neither of them show flights via South America, let alone Brazil.  All I can see is going via Europe and/or the Middle East, with a dash of India thrown in for good measure.

Answer (score 6):

[United's version of the Timatic software/database](https://www.united.com/web/en-US/apps/vendors/default.aspx?i=TIMATIC) states that you do not need a visa for Fiji but you should have evidence of onward travel.

You also will need:

> Vaccination against yellow fever required if arriving within 10 days after leaving or transiting countries with risk of yellow fever transmission.

The [Fijian Embassy in Washington D.C.](https://www.fijiembassydc.com/visas.htm) sums it up nicely:

> Requirements for Applicants from Exempted Countries
>
> - A valid passport that does not expire within 6 months from the date of departure from Fiji
> - Return air tickets showing the date of departure from Fiji or the country of your next visit
> - Proof that you have enough funds for your travel to Fiji in the form of a bank statement (translated in English)

If your are transiting in Brazil ON THE SAME TICKET, you do not need a visa. If you have separate tickets, you will need a visa.

Comment: You also need a visa if changing airports in Brazil, which happens occasionally.